# UWP - VisualStateManager.GoToState() does not work

Tags: uwp, state

I'm working the first time with the VisualStateManager. Unfortunatelly I don't get it running.

This is my XAML-Code:

```
<SplitView x:Name="spltvw" IsPaneOpen="False" DisplayMode="CompactInline" 
               CompactPaneLength="48" Grid.Row="1" PaneBackground="#FFDADADA">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="lowerThan7State">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="spltvw.DisplayMode" Value="Overlay" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="defaultState">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="spltvw.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        ....
</SplitView>
```

and this is my Code-behind:

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool test = false;
        if(IsScreenSizeLessThan7inches())
            test = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, lowerThan7State.Name, true);
        else
            test = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, defaultState.Name, true);
    }
```

I've already tried to change the "useTransitions"-parameter. I've debugged and tested the the "IsScreenSizeLessThan7inches()" method. But the result of this method is correct.

The return value of the GoToState() method is always false and the state of the SplittView-Control is also not changed.

I don't find the problem...

Please help me to find the error.

Thank you!

Comment: To simply Put, you are adding visual states inside SplitView to alter its state. Add the visual states outside the SplitView and it should work like a charm.

Comment: Yes. That was the solution! Thank you!

Comment: Please post what you did as an answer and mark it as an answer so that it can be helpful for others also.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of AVK was very helpfully.

I've put the VisualStateManager outside of the SplitView and now it works.

Here's what I've done:

```
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="lowerThan7State">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="spltvw.DisplayMode" Value="Overlay" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="defaultState">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="spltvw.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="48"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="#FFC31727" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="btn_hamburger" Width="48" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="btn_hamburger_Click">
            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE700;" Foreground="White" />
        </Button>
        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,80,0" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">
            ***-App
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,4,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/***_Logo_weiss.png" Height="44" />
    </Grid>
    <SplitView x:Name="spltvw" IsPaneOpen="False" DisplayMode="CompactInline" OpenPaneLength="250"
               CompactPaneLength="48" Grid.Row="1" PaneBackground="#FFDADADA" SizeChanged="spltvw_SizeChanged">
        ...
    </SplitView>
```